# Distance between 2 points without knowing coordinates

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have the following scenario depicted in the attached Figure. Assuming that there are no symmetries and any particular cases, assuming to know the distance $d_{12}$, the coordinates $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$ and the other distances depicted in the figure do you have any idea on how to compute the distance $dist$ between the 2 green points?[image]

Comment: I think you could use the law of cosines a few times and that should do it ...

Comment: This is not unique. I can take the point in blue and pull it to the right and then adjust the opposite point in red such that the distance remains $5$ without impacting any other length with $3$.

Comment: You need to know at least one more data point - either an angle or a length.

Comment: @MathLover which data point or length do you mean?

Comment: Any angle or length will do: you can use the sine rule and cosine rule to determine the rest of the lengths and angles. This is because in each triangle, you have two sides, and two sides + one angle or all three sides is sufficient.

Comment: Say either _dist_ or $d_{12}$ is given or any one of the angles between your various lines.

Comment: @MathLover the distance $d_{12}$ is given as I remarked in the question.

Comment: May be we did not understand that part from the question. I thought you were finding $d_{12}$. Since everything else had numerical values and those did not have.

Comment: What about _dist_? Is it given or you need to find?

Comment: I am assuming that is the length you need to find? If so apply law of sine / cosine. You should get there.

Comment: @MathLover I need to find $dist$. Only that one. By the way, please if you can, may I ask you to provide me an example about the usage of the cosine/sine rules for this problem?

Comment: OK I will.  Need to edit your diagram for that.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thank you so much @MathLover

Comment: I see @TobyMak has already updated that in his answer. Please follow that. I will not repeat the effort.

Comment: Solve the triangles $ABC$ and $ABD$, then using the angles, solve $BCD$.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated answer**:
[image]

First find $\angle (a+b)$ using the cosine rule in triangle $ABC$, then find $\angle a$ using the cosine rule in triangle $ABD$.

Then you can find angle $b$. Now use the cosine rule to find the distance between the green points $C$ and $D$.

You will need the following formulas:

$$c^2 = a^2+b^2 - 2ab \cos C \Rightarrow \cos C = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

$a,b$ are sides in this formula, and $c$ is the opposite side to the angle you are trying to find. $C$ is the angle you are trying to find. It does not matter which sides you choose as $a$ and $b$, as long as they are not opposite to the given angle.

---

[image]

Call the point $(x_2, y_2)$ $A$, the two green points $C$ and $D$, and point $(x_1, y_1)$ $B$.

If $C, D$ lie on a circle of radius $3$ centered at $A$, then $C$, $D$ are guaranteed to be exactly $3$ units from $A$. Similarly, by construction, $B$ lies $3$ units away from $C$ and $5$ units away from $D$.

Imagine moving $C$ and $D$ in the diagram. Thus the length of $CD$ is not fixed and can clearly vary.

Comment: What happens if D is distant 4 from A? Is it possible to model this scenario with a parametric equation?

Comment: That still doesn't change anything. The problem is not with the specific numbers in the setup, but rather the lack of sufficient information (either angles or lengths) as Math Lover has said.

Comment: Regarding your other point, you could definitely model this parametrically. If $A$ is the origin, $C = (3 \cos a, 3 \sin a)$ and $D = (3 \cos b, 3 \sin b)$, then you could find the coordinates of $B$ in terms of angles $a$ and $b$. There are however two possible options for $B$: you have to set some condition to choose just one of the intersections.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\color{green}{O}$, $\color{green}{A}$, $\color{orange}{B}$, $\color{blue}{C}$ be the four points in figure
( $\color{green}{O}$ is the green dot at left, $\color{green}{A}$ the green dot at right, $\color{orange}{B}, \color{blue}{D}$ the dots with corresponding color). Let

$$\begin{cases}
a_1 &= |OA| = \verb/dist/\\
b_1 &= |OB| = 3\\
c_1 &= |OC| = 3\\
\end{cases}\quad\text{ and }\quad
\begin{cases}
a &= |BC| = d_{12}\\
b &= |AC| = 5\\
c &= |AB| = 3
\end{cases}
$$

Since these four points lie on a plane, the volume of the tetrahedron formed by these points is zero. In general, if we know the edge lengths of a tetrahedron, we can compute its volume $V$ by evaluating corresponding  [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant):

$$288V^2 = \left|\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & a_1^2 & b_1^2 & c_1^2\\
1 & a_1^2 & 0 & c^2 & b^2\\
1 & b_1^2 & c^2 & 0 & a^2\\
1 & c_1^2 & b^2 & a^2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right|
$$
For the problem at hand, we have

$$V = 0 \iff
\left|\begin{matrix} 
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & a_1^2 & 3^2 & 3^2\\
1 & a_1^2 & 0 & 3^2 & 5^2\\
1 & 3^2 & 3^2 & 0 & a^2\\
1 & 3^2 & 5^2 & a^2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right| = 0
$$
Throwing this to a CAS, you can simplify this to an quadratic equation in $y = a_1^2$:

$$y^2 + (a^2-52)y + \frac{2304}{a^2} = 0$$
This leads to two possible solution for $OA = \verb/dist/ {}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$.

$$\verb/dist/ = a_1 = \sqrt{\frac{a(52-a^2) \pm \sqrt{a^6-104a^4+2704a^2-9216}}{2a}}$$

**note**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - For the configuration in figure, $O$ and $A$ lie on same side of $BC$, one should take the smaller root of $y$ (ie taking '-' sign in front of the inner square root) to get the right distance.